# MySQL order by IN array

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MySQL script like this: `SELECT id, name FROM users WHERE id IN (6,4,34)`

The sequence in the IN(...) array is very important. Is it possible to get them in the given sequence?

Answer (score 15):

You can use the [MySQL `FIELD` function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_field) to keep it compact;

```
SELECT id, name 
FROM users 
WHERE id IN (6, 4, 34)
ORDER BY FIELD(id, 6, 4, 34);
```

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
SELECT id, name FROM users WHERE id IN (6,4,34) order by FIELD(id,6,4,34)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use any expression in the ORDER BY clause, including a 'CASE':

```
ORDER BY CASE id 
  WHEN 6 THEN 1 
  WHEN 4 THEN 2 
  WHEN 34 THEN 3 
END ASC
```

If your list comes from the application programming layer, you might build this with the following (PHP here):

```
$sortVal = 1;
foreach($ids as $id_val) {
  $cases[] = sprintf('WHEN %i THEN %i', $id_val, $sortVal++);
}
$order_by = 'ORDER BY CASE id ' . implode($cases) . ' END ASC';
```

However, I'll mention that Joachim's answer is quite elegant :-)

Comment: Thanks, but I don't know the number before. I get the array with implode(",", $array)

Comment: @friction I added some example code to show how I might build the CASE clause.

Answer (score 0):

A complete example based on Chris Trahey answer.

```
$ids = array("table1",  "table2", "table3");
    
$sortVal = 1;
foreach ($ids as $id_val) {
    $cases[] = sprintf("WHEN '%s' THEN %u ", $id_val, $sortVal++);
}    
$order_by = 'ORDER BY CASE `tableName` ' . implode($cases) . ' END ASC';    

$result = mysqli_query( $con, "
        SELECT DISTINCT tableName 
        FROM `table` 
        $order_by");
```